# Rename object by taking input from a popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code :

```
<button ng-repeat="(name,content) in contacts" ng-dblclick="rename(name)">{{ name }}</button>
```

```
$scope.rename = function() {
    $scope.newname = prompt("Please reenter file name");
    // ... *incomplete*
}
```

I need the logic of rename function which takes the object's name as input and probably create a object with new name and same values as previous and delete the old object.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to delete an object and then create a new one, when you could just edit the object?

You could use `$index`, assuming `contacts` is an array containing objects with a `name` property:

`<button ng-repeat="contact in contacts" ng-dblclick="rename($index)"> {{ contact.name }} </button>`

```
$scope.rename = function(idx) {
    var newName = prompt("Please reenter file name");
    $scope.contacts[idx].name = newName;
 }
```

Another option would be to send the object itself to the function:

`<button ng-repeat="contact in contacts" ng-dblclick="rename(contact)"> {{ contact.name }} </button>`

```
$scope.rename = function(contact) {
    var newName = prompt("Please reenter file name");
    contact.name = newName;
 }
```